# I need to compare two values in JavaScript and based on those set a status to available

Tags: javascript

The project that I'm currently working on in is probably way out of my programming abilities, but I am giving it a try.

The following snippet of code is from my data.js, I need to compare these in my primary.js

```
    {
        index: 4,
        name: "",
        desc: "",
        type: "",
        ranks: 5,
        primary: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    },
    {
        index: 8,
        name: "",
        desc: "",
        type: "",
        ranks: 5,
        primary: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    },
```

-- this snippet of code is just from a data.js that stores a bunch of values

What I need to compare is the `"primary: [2,4,6,8,10],"` between the two indexes.

I'll try to explain this best I can, each number regardless of the number needs to be seen as a 1, so for `"primary: [2,4,6,8,10],"` it needs to count them as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on no matter if it was `"primary: [783,203,1294,240,143],"` or the previously mentioned example.

Anyways some snippets from my primary javascript that I think could be key:

```
var getParentIndex = function (tree, parent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _talents[tree].length; i++) {
        if (_talents[tree][i].index == parent) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

Adding new code to look at primary instead of parent could maybe be a step in the right direction:

```
var getPrimaryIndex = function (tree, primary) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _talents[tree].length; i++) {
        if (_talents[tree][i].index == primary) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

And then comparing values between two different indexes

**Very important is that if the values of the two different indexes primary is == X it needs to be put as available in this snippet of code**

```
                    if (pointsRequired(talent) <= treePoints(tree) && parentIsFull(tree, index))
                        status = (rank > 0) ? "active" : "available";
                    else
                        status = "unavailable";
                }
```

So something along the lines of:

```
                    if (pointsRequired(talent) <= treePoints(tree) && parentIsFull(tree, index) && primarycounter=5)
                        status = (rank > 0) ? "active" : "available";
                    else
                        status = "unavailable";
                }
```

I know you wouldnt write it as primarycounter=5 but its just to give an idea of the functionality I need.

I have uploaded the entirety of both my data.js and primary.js to github if that makes it any easier in any way.
https://github.com/chc544/Helpless

Comment: Do you know how to compare two arrays, and how to express the difference?  Maybe that's a simpler place to begin.

Comment: I dont know how to compare two arrays no, thank you I will look that up, and see if that could help!

Comment: I wanna let you know that from what you said and about 4 hours of reading different things on comparing arrays I figured it out, so big probs to you!

Comment: I am not native speaker, but it is hard to understand what are you looking for ;-) Maybe you should focus more on description of your target and reduce strange code. Or some testcases or examples and explanation why something is or is not active or available ?

Comment: yep, I agree. I should have been able to explain it in a more simple and straightforward way, but it was a fairly complex issue, so it wasn't easy to explain exactly what I wanted (probably mostly because I am extremely new at programming). I'm not a native speaker either though, so I understand the struggle in reading someone elses post, who is themselves not a native speaker either.